# Right-Action of fundamental group on universal cover

Tags: riemannian-geometry, group-actions, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups, geometric-group-theory

I think that the above action exists (of course presupposing a sufficiently nice base-space $X$) and is given by
$$Y\curvearrowleft\pi_1(X,x)\rightarrow Y, [\Gamma].[\gamma]=[\Gamma\circ\gamma]$$
where $x$ is a fixed point in the base space $X$, and $Y$ is the universal covering space modeled as the set of path-classes in $X$ which start at $x$. In the above, $\Gamma$ is any such path and $\gamma$ is an element of the fundamental group, i.e. w.l.o.g. a loop starting at $x$ and what I wrote is well-defined.

I think it is immediate that the above has the defining properties of a group action, but I can't find this result when googling so I'm not sure if maybe I did something wrong. Can someone confirm that this is indeed an action?

Bonus question: Why is this an action by isometries for compact, connected Riemannian Manifolds? I know how the metric on the universal cover is created but am not able to do the necessary calculations yet.

Comment: It's true for connected Riemmanian manifold (compact is unnecessary). First think how the Riemannian structure is defined on the universal cover.

Comment: Exercise: given a Riemannian manifold $X$ with a cover $f:Y\to X$, there is a unique Riemannian metric on $Y$ such that $f$ is a local isometry.

Comment: The distance of two points in the universal cover is the minimal length of the projection of some curve between those points to the base space. $d(y_1,y_2)=\min_{c:[0,1]\rightarrow Y,c(0)=y_1,c(1)=y_2}p\circ c$. And now?

Comment: why do you want to define the distance? defining the metric tensor is straightforward

Comment: But to understand a argument about Riemannian manifold you're supposed to know what a Riemannian manifold is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of this action does not make sense because it violates the definition of path concatenation. Here's why.

$\Gamma$ represents any path that starts at $x$. Let's consider the case that $\Gamma$ ends at a point $z \ne x$.

$\gamma$ represents a path that starts and ends at $x$.

In order for the concatenation $\Gamma \circ \gamma$ to be defined, the endpoint of $\Gamma$ (which is $z$) must equal the starting point of $\gamma$ (which is $x$). Since $z \ne x$, it follows that the concatenation $\Gamma \circ \gamma$ is not defined.

Comment: Ok. The reason I'm looking at this 'action' is that apparently the fundamental group of Riemannian manifolds is quasi-isometric to their universal cover. This is is sold as a trivial corollary of Svarc-Milnor everywhere in the literature, but I could never find a fully spelled out proof of how this is supposed to work. I assumed that maybe the way to go was to prove what I claimed in this question. Since this is not the case, could you please point me to some reference where the quasi-isom. is proven, or sketch the proof for me. I have absolutely no clue where to go from here.

Comment: Well, you can use the left action $\gamma \circ \Gamma$...

Comment: This is actually the action I meant. For some reason I thought I could write path-concatenation as normal function composition, and ended up with what I wrote in the opening post. So this is indeed an action of the fundamental group on the universal cover, nice. Does it have a name? Also, are you aware of an argument why this is an action by isometries for the pull-back metric on thre universal cover? Anyways, thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: It does not go by any particular name that I know, people refer to it as simply "the left action of $\pi_1(X,x)$ on the universal cover".

Answer (score 0):

Essentially this action has the property that it restricts to each fiber of the covering map $Y \to X$. The action on each fiber is called the **monodromy action**, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy.

I guess it can be a left action on $Y$ as @LeeMosher points out. When restricting the action to just the fiber $F = \pi^{-1}(x)$ it can be a right action (as on Wikipedia) if $[\Gamma].[\gamma] = [\Gamma \cdot \tilde\gamma]$ where $\tilde\gamma$ is the lift of $\gamma$ that starts at the endpoint of $\Gamma$.